# Acer Wireless Network not working

Tags: wireless, touchpad, acer

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit desktop version in acer AspireE1-470. Everything work great except Wireless and touch pad. When i run additional driver there nothing to activate and when i run "rfkill list" it's show

```
0: hci0:bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless Lan
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I don't know too much command in linux and i hv no i ieda hot to work wireless and touch-pad

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: thz for ur reply i will try it. How do u think about TouchPad. Sorry about my question title i forget to mention TouchPad also

Comment: Hello there this is wireless-info
[url]http://pastebin.com/ZtUnTEgf[/url]

Comment: It says your post at pastebin was removed, did you remove it?

Comment: No i didn't, but i will post it again.

Answer (score 0):

The following will help get the touch pad working.

Try the following

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
>
> synclient TouchpadOff=0
>
> sudo chmod +wrx '/var/lib/dpkg/lock'
>
> sudo apt-get install synaptic

Run the following command to check if the touch pad is installed

> lsmod
>
> lsmod | grep psmouse

Depending on the output try the following command to install/reinstall the touch pad
 module.

> sudo modprobe -r psmouse
>
> sudo modprobe psmouse

For more details refer to the following link

[12.04 Touchpad not working Asus g51vx-A1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967228&page=2&s=62c66755419894eab84d354649d1ea2b)